# Accessing dynamically generated DOM elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamically-generated

I am working on a (homework) project, building a web app that provides some basic Select, Insert, Update and Delete operations to a MySQL database.

What I have done:

1) I have built an MVC / Active Record(ish) architectrure in PHP for the backend

2) I have created a tab and menu based enviroment in the front end using jQuery and jQuery UI. Specifically the user chooses the table he wants to access with the tab he chooses and the operation he wants to perform with a menu. Once a menu item is chosen I create dynamically the DOM elements to compose a form with an AJAX call.

So the only part remaining is to complete the communication between those two components. I have decided to do this with a .submit() event that iterates over the fields of the form, takes the necessary information (the ids and the values of the elements) and performs an post / ajax call to php to send the information.

My question is, since I cannot access directly a dynamically generated DOM in jQuery, how can I do this? Many of the relevant questions in stackoverflow where deprecated so I posted this one.
Thanks.

Comment: You should delegate submit event, e.g: `$(document).on("submit", "form", function (e) {e.preventDefault(); /* validation logic here */});`

Comment: Wow that was quick. So I can do something like $.each{".form", function()} there to access each element of the form?

Comment: Sure you can access anything you want. FYI, you can serialize data: `var formDatas = $(this).serialize();` https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ **OR** https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I got worked up with the code and I forgot to thank you!

Comment: Don't worry, glad you have it working now! ;)